# Qt6/PySide6 - how to position graphics elements

Tags: pyqt

I'm new to Qt and trying to figure out how position graphics items?

For example, I want to overlay some text onto a video. However, instead of overlaying them, the text is vertically stacked above the video.

[image]

My code is below, I've tried setting the position of the video/text elements (e.g. `video.setPos(0,0)`) but it didn't work. I also tried using QGraphicsLayout but ran into problems adding the video/text elements.

```py
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self)
        
        # Create a QT player
        player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(self)
        player.setSource(QtCore.QUrl("https://archive.org/download/SampleVideo1280x7205mb/SampleVideo_1280x720_5mb.mp4"))
        
        video = QtMultimediaWidgets.QGraphicsVideoItem()
        player.setVideoOutput(video)
        
        text = QtWidgets.QGraphicsTextItem("Hello World")
        
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        scene.addItem(video)
        scene.addItem(text)
        
        view.setScene(scene)
        view.setFixedSize(800,800)
        player.play()
        player.setLoops(-1)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(800, 800)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by two aspects:

1. QGraphicsVideoItem has a *default* [`size`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsvideoitem.html#size-prop) of `320x240`; for conceptual and optimization reasons, it does *not* change its size when video content is loaded or changed;
2. the video you're using has a different aspect ratio: `320x240` is `4:3`, while the video is `1280x720`, which is the standard widescreen ratio, `16:9`;

By default, QGraphicsVideoItem just adapts the video contents to its *current* size, respecting the [`aspectRatioMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsvideoitem.html#aspectRatioMode-prop). The result is that you get some blank space above and below the video, similarly to what was common when showing movies in old TVs ("[letterboxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_(filming))"):

[image: Example of letterboxing from Wikipedia]

Since graphics items are always positioned using the top left corner of their [coordinate system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system), you see a *shifted* image. In fact, if you just print the `boundingRect` of the video item when playing starts, you'll see that it has a vertical offset:

```
    player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(lambda: print(video.boundingRect()))

# result:
QtCore.QRectF(0.0, 30.0, 320.0, 180.0)
                   ^^^^ down by 30 pixels!
```

There are various possibilities to solve this, but it all depends on your needs, and it all resorts on connecting to the [`nativeSizeChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsvideoitem.html#nativeSizeChanged) signal. Then it's just a matter of properly setting the size, adjust the content to the visible viewport area, or eventually always call [`fitInView()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView-2) while adjusting the position of other items (and ignoring transformations).

For instance, the following code will keep the existing size (`320x240`) but will change the [`offset`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsvideoitem.html#offset-prop) based on the adapted size of the video:

```py
        # ...
        self.video = QtMultimediaWidgets.QGraphicsVideoItem()
        # ...
        self.video.nativeSizeChanged.connect(self.updateOffset)

    def updateOffset(self, nativeSize):
        if nativeSize.isNull():
            return
        realSize = self.video.size()
        scaledSize = nativeSize.scaled(realSize, 
            QtCore.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio)
        yOffset = (scaledSize.height() - realSize.height()) / 2
        self.video.setOffset(QtCore.QPointF(0, yOffset))
```

Comment: Great detail! And thank you for the `nativeSizeChanged` signal... I noticed the QGraphicsVideoItem had a `sizeChanged` signal but whenever I tried to connect it to a slot and read the video size, everything hung. Very helpful seeing this.

Comment: @Alter Where did you see the `sizeChanged` signal? QGraphicsVideoItem has no such thing...

Comment: QT6 QGraphicsVideoItem uses QVideoSink (there's a property for it), and the [python documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtMultimedia/QVideoSink.html) shows a signal for sizeChanged... except I just checked the [C++ docs for it](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvideosink.html#QVideoSink) and it doesn't show a signal so that's strange

Comment: It was triggering, I would just get an error if I tried to then read the videoSize from it

Comment: @Alter Ok, please be more precise, you meant the `videoSizeChanged` of QVideoSink. I've noticed that the Qt6 documentation of the QtMultimedia modules is a bit inconsistent (especially between the C++ and the Python docs), I hope they will fix and clarify those aspects in the next releases. In the meantime, always refer to the standard API (C++) and eventually look for the Python docs *after*. This is what you should normally do anyway for any Qt docs.